# Filter by/Aggregate multiple columns in Power BI

Tags: group-by, powerbi

I would like to group by item and count for each store how many rows are there for my sales data.

table:

```
Id   Item   Store   Qty 
1    A      store1  5
2    B      store1  2
3    A      store2  3
4    B      store2  10
  ....
```

To group by item I tried:

```
groupby_item = SUMMARIZE(table, table[Item], "Count", COUNT(table[Item]))
```

which gives the table:

```
Item   Count 
A      2
B      2
```

but I want to introduce a `Store` slicer in a visual and I couldn't because `Store` column is absent in the aggregated table. Can I group by Store then by item and count?

Like in Python you could maybe do:

```
table.groupby('Item').agg({'Store': 'first', 'Id': 'count'})
```

to keep the `Store` information by keeping the first value of `Store` in each item group.

Would you be able to do that in Power BI? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why create an aggregate table in the first place?  You can use the base table in the visual and it would reflect any filters on Store.

The default behavior of PBI visuals is to group categorical columns and aggregate numerical ones.